# Display the port an application is using if it is not permanent

Tags: linux, networking

How can I get the port an application is using, if it is not using this port permanently.

So lets say I want to find out the default port `sendfile` or `sendmsg` is using, how can I do this?

I was imagining something like:

```
sendmsg user@hostname -s "hello" | checkport
```

Comment: What do you mean with "using a port permanently"? Is there a `sendmsg` utility too? I'm only familiar with the system call, and can't find any reference to a tool of that name, at least on a quick search.

Comment: @ilkkachu oh sorry, `sendmsg` is part of the package `sendfile`, using a protocol calling himself `saft` I'm truing to configure `firwalld` to accept incoming calls from this application or the appropriate IP in general but can't figure out the port it is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outgoing ports are random.  Ports to connect to are static.  You can see what port any given process is using by using `netstat` with some options - I like `netstat -tapn`

The `t` option makes it show TCP stuff (not unix sockets, etc)

The `a` is "all" - both connecting/established and listening ports

The `p` is "show me the process ID number"

The `n` is "don't look up service names in /etc/services for ports or host names for IPs"

Comment: `Outgoing ports are random` thank you. There has been a wrong understanding how this, let me call it `port-management` works from my site. So I have to specify a port for the outgoing connection, and for the firewall to allow this connection on this port on the other site. (maybe I should have addressed a question concerning `firewalld`). But this helped ma allot!